# Getting terms for only one taxonomy from services module

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

I have the services module installed, and I have both `taxonomy_term` and `taxonomy_vocabulary` checked. However I'm having problems getting just the terms for one vocabulary. when I do `curl -g "http://domain.com/endpoint/taxonomy_term?args[0]=machine_name_of_vocabulary"` or `curl -g "http://domain.com/endpoint/taxonomy_term?args[0]=2"`

I get an xml result like this:

```
<result>
  <item>
    <tid>2</tid>
    <vid>2</vid>
    <name>Blue</name>
    <description/>
    <format>filtered_html</format>
    <weight>0</weight>
  </item>
  <item>
    <tid>1</tid>
    <vid>5</vid>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <description/>
    <format>filtered_html</format>
    <weight>0</weight>
  </item>
</result>
```

which is the terms of all the vocabularies. In other words, I have the argument wrong, or the request wrong, or something else wrong.

How do I configure services and make a request to it to get only one vocabulary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was working on exactly the same thing the other day, the format is like this:

```
http://domain.com/endpoint/taxonomy_term?parameters[vid]=2
```

To explain that a bit further...

If you look at the code in [`_taxonomy_resource_definition()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!services!resources!taxonomy_resource.inc/function/_taxonomy_resource_definition/7) the *index* resource defines a few arguments:

- page (int)
- fields (string)
- parameters (array)
- pagesize (int)

The way to pass any of those is:

```
http://domain.com/endpoint/taxonomy_term?arg_name=value
```

Since `parameters` is an array you need to format it as if it was an associative array in the URL, so you use (e.g.) `parameters[vid]=2`.

It will also work for other parameters, e.g. `parameters[name]=TermName`.

Answer (score 0):

For Services 3.x on Drupal7, this also works:

```
curl -i -X POST \
 -H Cookie:SESSabcdefg12345baadbeef=ovQpBase62SessionIdHere_45AUSJ \
 -H X-CSRF-Token:v6j7r9RactujAHY-mYYZa \
 -H Accept:application/json \
 -H content-type:application/json \
 'http://services.example.com/rest/taxonomy_vocabulary/getTree' \
 -d '{ "vid" :"1" }'
```

Why?

Not sure. Not sure why they duplicated the capability. Also not sure why this is a POST. Someone on a drupal board said that it is because retrieving these things is "an action" and "actions" need to be done with POST. It didn't make sense to me. It looks like a query, not an action. But whatever.

But I like the [other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/43943/26722) better.